# Вывод записей в виде списка прикрепленной к группе

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы в mysql. Одна хранит информацию о группе, в другой хранятся списки по id группы.

```
SELECT *
FROM `group`,`dialog`
WHERE `group`.id = `dialog`.group_id
LIMIT 50
```

По данному примеру выводится столько групп, сколько и списков. Нужно выводить одну группу и весь список по этой группе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает GROUP BY в MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-group-by-%d0%b2-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите (советую указать в вопросе структуру таблиц), используйте функцию [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php):

```
SELECT g.id, GROUP_CONCAT(d.spisok)
FROM `group` g join `dialog` d ON g.id = d.group_id
GROUP BY g.id
LIMIT 50
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccff05/1/0).

Comment: Если вы правильно угадали, то вопрос стоило бы закрыть по дублю ибо подобных вопросов/ответов уже есть 100500 штук

Comment: А как выводить это через цикл? Ибо я не в ладах с группировками записей, не пойму как вывести сначала id группы и после список... Или нужно 2 цикла?

Comment: @Mike вообще вы правы, их тут уже навалом таких вопросов.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков цикл не нужен, всё сделает `GROUP_CONCAT`. посмотрите пример на sqlfiddle, обновил ответ.

Comment: Не работает у меня. Вывожу d.spisok в виде $group['spisok'] и ничего (В место spisok соответственно свое поле). Но группы выводятся правильно. Списки нет.

Comment: Ааа все получилось, добавил AS к  GROUP_CONCAT и заработало.

Comment: @Denis Извините, такой вариант не подходит. Мне ведь нужно будет добавлять условия при выводе для списка, а так я могу лишь только выводить. Можно ли как то добавлять этот список в массив?

Comment: @АльбертУшаков каков был вопрос - такой ответ)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $sql_dialog = mysql_query("SELECT f.*, GROUP_CONCAT(d.d_title) AS dialog_title
    FROM fandom f join dialog d ON f.id = d.d_fandom
    GROUP BY f.id");
    while($dialog = mysql_fetch_array($sql_dialog)){
    $list_vivod = null;
        $dialog_list = explode(',',$dialog['dialog_title']);
        foreach($dialog_list AS $list){
            $list_vivod .= '<list class="list-box-spisok">'.$list.'</list>'; 
        }
    print<<<HERE
    $dialog[id]
    $list_vivod
    HERE;
    }
```