# Вывести только уникальные значения?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть такой вот массив.

```
Array (
    0 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Для Женщин', [tac_title] => 'Для кого' ),
    1 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Серебро 925', [tac_title] => 'Металл' ),
    2 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Фианит', [tac_title] => 'Вставка' ),
    3 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Горный хрусталь' [tac_title] => 'Вставка' ),
    4 => Array ([tav_title] => 'SOKOLOV' [tac_title] => 'Бренд'),
);
```

Вывожу его вот так:

```
<?php foreach ($res as $item):?>
    <b><?= $item['tac_title'] ?></b>: <?= $item['tav_title'] ?><br> 
<? endforeach;?>
```

Выглядит он так:

```
Для кого: Для Женщин
Металл: Серебро 925
Вставка: Фианит
Вставка: Горный хрусталь
Бренд: SOKOLOV
```

Как видно, поле вставка повторяется несколько раз, а значение разное. Как можно вывести вот так?

```
Для кого: Для Женщин
Металл: Серебро 925
Вставка: Фианит, Горный хрусталь
Бренд: SOKOLOV
```

Если поможет, то ниже MySql запрос.

```
SELECT `t_a_v`.`title` AS 'tav_title', `t_a_c`.`title` AS 'tac_title'
FROM `tm_attr_value` AS `t_a_v` 
LEFT JOIN `tm_attr_category` AS `t_a_c`
    ON `t_a_c`.`id` = `t_a_v`.`id_attr_category`
WHERE `t_a_v`.`id` = '$attrValue'
```

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально "mySql" запрос, можно голову сломать. По вопросу, либо перед выводом обработайте свой массив сложив строки и удалив ненужные элементы массива либо напишите mysql запрос.

Comment: @koks_rs Оставил только запрос!

Comment: Добавьте группировку и используйте group_concat для получения списка через запятую. Аналогичный вопрос был пару часов назад http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574806  и еще 100500 ответов, искать тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+group_concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях я всегда делаю, предподготовку данных перед выводом:

```
$result = [ // результат выполнения sql
    0 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Для Женщин', [tac_title] => 'Для кого' ),
    1 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Серебро 925', [tac_title] => 'Металл' ),
    2 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Фианит', [tac_title] => 'Вставка' ),
    3 => Array ([tav_title] => 'Горный хрусталь', [tac_title] => 'Вставка' ),
    4 => Array ([tav_title] => 'SOKOLOV', [tac_title] => 'Бренд'),
];

// подготовка данных
$data = [];
foreach($result => $item) {
    $data[$item[tac_title]] = $item[tav_title];
}

// таким образом получу подходящий массив $data:
// 'Для кого' => 'Для Женщин',
// 'Металл' => 'Серебро 925',
// 'Вставка' => ['Фианит', 'Горный хрусталь'],
// 'Бренд' => 'SOKOLOV',

// вывод
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value):?>
    <b><?= $key ?></b>: 
    <?php if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $elem) {
            echo $elem.',';
        }
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
    ?><br> 
<? endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT t_a_c.title as tac_title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t_a_v.title ORDER BY t_a_v.title ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS tav_title
FROM tm_attr_value t_a_v 
LEFT JOIN tm_attr_category t_a_c ON t_a_c.id = t_a_v.id_attr_category
WHERE t_a_v.id = '$attrValue'
```