# Как работает GROUP BY в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Привет.

Вопрос по `sql` по клаузуле `GROUP BY`.

1. Рассмотрим группировку по **ОДНОМУ** столбцу. Пример:

   ```
   SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, SUM(SALARY) 
   FROM Employees
   GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID;
   ```

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   То есть, в столбце `DEPARTMENT_ID` ищется **уникальное** (похоже на `DISTINCT`) значение отдела, например, 30, затем ищутся **все** строки, где упоминается отдел 30 в данной таблице, из этих строк берутся значения из столбца `SALARY` и **суммируются** (`SUM`). Потом ищется **другой** покупатель и все повторяется. В итоге я получаю сколько получил вообще денег каждый отдел.

   Не понимаю момент: у меня есть 6 строк, в которых есть столбец `DEPARTMENT_ID` со значением 30. Какая из строк пойдет в таблицу-`SELECT` и почему? То есть, в таблице `Employees` было **шесть** строк с `DEPARTMENT_ID` 30, а в таблице-`SELECT` такая строка только **одна**. Как вообще эта группировка работает?
2. Рассмотрим группировку по **двум** столбцам. Ее я вообще не понимаю. Даже картинки нормальной не нашел, из которой было бы понятно. Просмотрел кучу статей и книг по этому вопросу, но не понял ничего.

Comment: А что вас смущает? Да, при группировке выбирается первая прочитанная строка из группы, т. е., если в таблице `Employees` было ШЕСТЬ строк с `DEPARTMENT_ID` 30, то в таблице `SELECT` такая строка будет только ОДНА, и остальные поля, которые выбирались из первой таблицы `SELECT`'ом, но не вошли в `GROUP BY`, будут соответствовать первой прочитанной строке из группы с `DEPARTMENT_ID = 30`

Comment: где это написано, что выбирается именно ПЕРВАЯ строка? не встречал

Comment: http://webnotes.by/docs/sql/osobennosti-group-by-v-mysql например, тут

Comment: @Mike +1 про другие СУБД. Вообще странное поведение MySQL, первый раз счас про него прочитал :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Добавлю с примером запросов и вывода GROUP BY по двух полях. 
Смотреть можно по таблице в которую, например, сохраняеться какой пользователь (user_id) вносил деньги, на какой счет (account) и сколько (balance).
Например, нужно узнать сколько каждый пользователь внес на каждый из своих счетов.

```
SELECT MIN(user_id), MIN(account), SUM(balance) FROM `t1` GROUP BY user_id, account;
```

Работает GROUP BY по двум полям так же как и по одному, сначала сортирует, а потом смотрит, если оба значения в строке такие же как и в предыдущей строке, тогда групирует эти строки. Если хотя бы одно значение не такое как в предыдущей строке, тогда групировки не будет. Для 3 и больше полей GROUP BY работает так же.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 26):

В выборку после `group by` не попадет ни одна из изначальных строк. На выходе агрегат - сумма данных в нужном разрезе. К колонкам, к которым вы явно не применили никаких групповых функций (таких как `sum()`), будет применена функция "первое попавшееся". Причем только в MySQL и только при выключенной опции `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. В остальных СУБД запрос, в котором хотя бы к одной колонке, не являющейся разрезом указанным в group by, "забыли" применить групповую функцию выдаст ошибку.

Как работает `group by` можно прикинуть в экселе. Запишите данные на лист, отсортируйте по тем полям, которые должны быть в `group by`. Читая отсортированные данные подряд в любом случае когда значение в очередной строке в колонках, указанных в `group by` отличается от значений в предыдущей - вставьте новую строку, скопируйте значения колонок `group by`, а в остальные поместите формулы вроде `СУММ()` ячеек группы под которой подводится итог. Результат `group by` - это именно эти вставленные итоговые записи. СУБД работает примерно по такому же алгоритму - сначала сортирует, потом суммирует идущие подряд одинаковые записи.

Добавлю про MySQL - он все таки слишком вольно к этому относится. Старайтесь всегда явно применять групповые функции ко всем колонкам, что бы самому понимать что именно в них окажется, ибо 'первое попавшееся' ни чем не стандартизировано и может меняться от версии к версии и в зависимости от физического расположения записей на диске и плана выполнения запроса.