# Как выбрать последние строки из строк соответствующих условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно получить из таблицы, имена всех клиентов, которые активны (совершали транзакции не меньше минуты назад)

Сейчас у меня выводит список, но имена повторяются, так как за эту минуту каждый клиент совершал несколько транзакций, как мне в запросе отсеять повторяющиеся имена

```
SELECT `client` 
FROM `tranzactions` 
WHERE `eventtime` >  SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL "00:01" HOUR_MINUTE)
```

Comment: Сгруппировать. Или, если нужно только одно поле, то DISTINCT.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, если не сложно, примером

Comment: @Akina  я почитал про DISTINCT, как я понял это не то, в таблице может быть много строк с именем каждого клиента, мне нужны по одной строке от каждого, у которого время последней транзакции не меньше минуты назад

Comment: А вы не только читайте, а пробуйте. distinct сделает именно то, что вам и нужно (так же как и group by)

Comment: Не правильно записывал, верно так тоже работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Mike я так понимаю DISTINCT находит первую строку, которая соответствует условию и если находит вторую с тем же клиентом ее  "отбрасывает", то есть DISTINCT возвращает первую строку из подходящих. А group by, вернет последнюю?

Comment: Нет, вы все неправильно понимаете. У SQL есть строгая очередность выполнения. Сначала берутся таблицы из from, потом к их записям применяются условия в where. После этого у нас считайте есть таблица состоящая из записей прошедших отбор. Вот к ней уже применяется distinct, который оставляет только уникальные значения выборки, либо group by, который записи группирует до указанного разреза и выдает только итоговые строки. Ни в том ни в другом случае понятия "первый" и "последний" в принципе не существует потому как изначальных строк уже нет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `client` 
FROM `tranzactions` 
WHERE `eventtime` >  SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL "00:01" HOUR_MINUTE)
GROUP BY 'client'
```