# Вывод GROUP BY записей с ASC сортировкой

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Есть таблица test.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно вытащить одну строку, группировка по сумме (amount), но если есть is_read=0 - то выводить именно эту строку.

Пробовал так

```
SELECT id, is_read FROM test GROUP BY amount ORDER BY is_read ASC;
```

Выводит только первую строку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести так, чтобы выводилось сортируя по is_read=0?

Чтобы был результат такой:

```
id=3, is_read=0
```

Comment: Вообще странно, что ошибки не выскочило, потому что при группировке нельзя выбирать поля, которые являются неоднозначными... ибо как бедная БД должна понять какие значения полей для тебя являются релевантными.  ты понимаешь что поведение происходит непредсказуемое и если один раз тебе is_read вынет равной 1, то в другой раз может и 0, а может и 666, если такое значение будет.... а вот предположим, что тебе надо всё же брать где `is_read = 1`, то какой `id` ты тогда ожидаешь увидеть? 1? 2? А если записей тысяча?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если брать конкретный is_read (555), то ид увидеть тот у которого is_read=555. Почему ошибка выскочить должна? Сначала выводит все записи, группируя по amount, и те которые есть уже группирует по is_read

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто когда оно группирует по полю amount, по записям идет с 0 до конца по идее, вот и хотелось бы вытащить тот, который ближе к последнему.

Comment: ну ты представь, что у тебя 100 записей имеют is_read = 555 и все они имеют значение amount = 2122 и ты группируешь по amount... группировка выдает **только одну** запись с таким конкретным amount.... какой идентификатор ты надеешься увидеть в выборке?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для начала идет GROUP BY, значит из всех 100 записей если сортировать по is_read555 - после сортировки будет 1 запись, а от ORDER BY уже  толку и нет, потому что после GROYP запись 1.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот и хотелось бы, чтобы GROUP BY amount выдавал ту запись, у которой is_read=0, а не 1.

Comment: ты не понимаешь что я говорю и то, как работает GROUP BY.... GROUP BY возвращает строку, какую ему вздумается, в итоге ты можешь получить в выборке какой угодно `id`. Если у тебя is_read = 0 имеет 50 записей, и идентификаторы этих записей 4,5,6,7,8 и т.д. то GROUP BY будет возвращать постоянно разные их значения. потому что `It's indeterminate which row will be returned. MySQL is free to return values from any row in the group.`..... Тебя устраивает такой рандом?

Comment: может так будет понятнее http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я понял, что из списка строк выдает рандомную, это есть ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: @user190134 Нет, из списка не выводит рандомную запись, изначальных строк, которые можно было бы выводить не остается вовсе. А это значит, что одно поле может быть из одной записи, а другое поле вообще из другой. т.е. никто ему не мешает показать id=2 и is_read=0 (хотя конечно на практике так вряд ли будет, потому что СУБД все таки не будут специально перебирать разные колонки в разном порядке, но в теории _имеют право_) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql/599802#599802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот таким образом:

```
select id, is_read, amount from test group by amount, is_read
order by amount, is_read
limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5de99/4

Comment: @Mike добавил сортировку еще.

Comment: тогда проще один запрос `group by amount, is_read order by is_read limit 1` правда что то мне подсказывает, что разных amount может быть несколько и тогда никакие лимиты не помогут

Comment: @Mike да, кстати :D

Comment: @Mike order by amount, is_read в этом случаи поможет?

Comment: вряд ли. id там по хорошему вообще не имеет права находится, потому как не указан в group by и от него не взят агрегат. это только mysql (причем не во всех конфигурациях) и sqlite позволяют такие вольности. единственный прямой путь, если диалект поддерживает оконные функции, нумеровать записи в правильном порядке в разрезе группировки (over(partition by amount order by is_read))и брать первые записи. Или эмулировать то же переменными в MySQL или применять магию sqlite "having min(is_read)"

Comment: @Mike по поводу ID поправил коммент, там имелось ввиду amount. Он берет первые два по возрастанию amount, группирует и выдает первый что имеется.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY возвращает строку, **какую ему вздумается**, в итоге ты можешь получить в выборке какой угодно id. Если у тебя is_read = 0 имеет 50 записей, и идентификаторы этих записей 4,5,6,7,8 и т.д. то GROUP BY будет возвращать постоянно разные их значения. потому что It's indeterminate which row will be returned. MySQL is free to return values from any row in the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, (select id from test t2 where t1.amount=t2.amount)  
and t2.is_read=mp limit 1) id
from 
(select amount, min(is_read) mp from test group by amount) t1
```