# Разные результаты после изменения набора полей

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь написать запрос. Но по сути почти 2 одинаковых запроса выдают разный результат.
Вот первый вариант запроса:

```
select p.CREATE_DATE, m.BATCH_ID, p.BATCH_ID, 
       s.BATCH_ID, s.CREATE_DATE, p.WC_INSTANCE, 
       s.WC_INSTANCE 
from   WC_MAIN m
left   join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p 
on     m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID 
and    m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR 
and    m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
left   join WC_7_3_SGP s 
on     m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID 
and    m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR 
and    m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
where  s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null 
and    s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null 
and    p.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    s.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    m.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    m.BATCH_ID = 252081
group  by p.CREATE_DATE, 
       m.BATCH_ID, 
       p.BATCH_ID, 
       s.BATCH_ID, 
       s.CREATE_DATE, 
       p.WC_INSTANCE, 
       s.WC_INSTANCE
having min(p.CREATE_DATE) >= max(s.CREATE_DATE);
```

А вот второй вариант:

```
select p.CREATE_DATE 
from   WC_MAIN m
left   join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p 
on     m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID 
and    m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR 
and    m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
left   join WC_7_3_SGP s 
on     m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID 
and    m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR 
and    m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
where  s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null 
and    s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null 
and    p.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    s.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    m.EDIT_STATE = 0 
and    m.BATCH_ID = 252081
group  by p.CREATE_DATE
having min(p.CREATE_DATE) >= max(s.CREATE_DATE);
```

Результаты первого и второго запроса различаются, точнее второй вообще ничего не  возвращает.
В чём дело? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Разный `group by`

Comment: @gil9red а как сделать group by одинаковым для разного количества полей? Просто если например я делаю select на 3 поля а группирую по 1 то выдаёт ошибку. Как это исправить?

Comment: *как сделать group by одинаковым для разного количества полей?* Нельзя уменьшить - но можно увеличить. Сделайте GROUP BY во втором вопросе таким же, как в первом, по всем 7 полям.

Comment: `... вот первый запрос ... и его результат ... вот выборка которую делает первый запрос` Непонятно, почему запрос один и тот же, а результат у него разный.

Comment: @defaultlocale смотрите 3 скриншот, его делает мой первый запрос, только с другим PIPE_NUMBER который как раз есть на скриншоте третьего запроса. А второй запрос с таким же намбером уже нечего не выдаёт. В чём тут может быть дело?

Comment: @defaultlocale если нужно могу подправить темку и убрать лишние скриншоты если так будет проще. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @defaultlocale подправил темку, оставил только нужное.

Comment: Если запрос с having ничего не вернул, выполните его без having и посмотрите записи которые получились, возможно по ним вы поймете что идет не так. вообще если вы группируете по s.create_date в having min(s.create_date) выглядит странно, потому как минимум от одного значения (ведь разбивка именно по нему) равен самому значению. Еще мне кажется вы не понимаете, что такое группировка, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/#599802

Comment: И если с группировкой что то идет не так, может проблема возникла еще до группировки ? Выполните буквально "select *" для части запроса, до группировки, там где все таблицы уже есть. И прикиньте по данным которые видите, какие преобразования вам над ними дальше нужны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хотя по сути во втором запросе я просто убрал несколько полей для выборки

Не только. Еще Вы убрали несколько полей из группировки.

Раньше в выборку попадали разные сочетания `p.create_date` и `s.create_date`, например.

[image: Выделенные группы]

Теперь записи не группируются по `s.create_date` и эти группы объединяются в одну (с `p.create_date` равным 30.04.15).

**Дополнение:**

Если Вы попытаетесь группировать по одному полю (`p.create_date`), а вывести другое (`s.create_date`), то база выдаст ошибку. Эта ошибка говорит о том, что БД не знает что сделать с ситуациями, когда данные нельзя выбрать однозначно. Например, в примере по `p.create_date` равному 30.04.15 есть три записи с разными значениями `s.create_date`.

Для разрешения неоднозначностей можно использовать агрегатные функции (`min`, `max`, `avg` и др. Смотрите [список в документации Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e12048/funcbltag.htm#CQLLR406)). Например, чтобы сгруппировать по `p.create_date` и получить по каждой записи минимальную `s.create_date` можно использовать следующий запрос:

```
select p.CREATE_DATE, min(s.create_date)
from WC_MAIN m
    left join WC_4_8_PRIEMKA p on m.SHOP_ID = p.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = p.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = p.PIPE_NUMBER
    left join WC_7_3_SGP s on m.SHOP_ID = s.SHOP_ID and m.PIPE_YEAR = s.PIPE_YEAR and m.PIPE_NUMBER = s.PIPE_NUMBER
where s.ORDER_NUM_RES is null and s.ORDER_ITEM_RES is null and p.EDIT_STATE = 0 and s.EDIT_STATE = 0 and m.EDIT_STATE = 0 and m.BATCH_ID = 1874074
group by p.CREATE_DATE
having min(p.CREATE_DATE) >= max(s.CREATE_DATE);
```

Аналогично с остальными полями. Нужно принять решение, либо группировать по этому полю, либо явно указывать какое значение нужно выбрать.

**Дополнение 2 по различию между запросами**

Использование агрегатных функций для сгруппированных полей не имеет смысла.

Например, здесь

```
group by p.create-date, s.create_date
having min(p.create_date) >= max(s.create_date)
```

`min` и `max` не имеют смысла, т.к. речь идет каждый раз об одном значении. Это условие эквивалентно условию без агрегатных функций:

```
group by p.create_date, s.create_date
having p.create_date >= s.create_date
```

Из этого следует еще одно различие между двумя запросами:

- В первом запросе выбираются все записи у которых `p.create_date` >= `s.create_date` и результат группируется.
- Во втором запросе записи сначала группируются по `p.create_date` затем для каждого обнаруживается максимальное значение `s.create_date` и выводятся только те записи, по которым оно не превосходит `p.create_date`.

Т.о. если есть записи `p.create_date` по которым имеются значения `s.create_date` как больше так и меньше, например:

```
 p.create_date   s.create_date
 01.01.16        01.01.15
 01.01.16        01.01.17
```

то 01.01.16 попадет в первую выборку, т.к. по нему имеется хотя бы одно значение меньше; но не попадет во вторую, т.к. максимальное значение `s.create_date` больше.

Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно точно определиться с требованиями.

З.Ы. Старайтесь [не благодарить людей заранее](http://bureau.ru/bb/soviet/20130512/). Это, как правило, неэффективно даже в первый раз, а при многократном повторении приносит обратный эффект.На Stackoverflow лучше сконцентрироваться на создании ясного, четко сформулированного вопроса.

Comment: А как можно сгруппировать мой первый вариант запроса только по 1 полю? У меня почему то не получается и выдаёт ошибку. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Андрей сначала нужно понять какой результат Вы хотите получить. Посмотрите: по первой дате (`p.create_date`) 30.04.15 есть три разные вторые даты (`s.create_date`). Какая из них должна отображаться в сгруппированном результате?

Comment: Первый вариант 29.10.14

Comment: @Андрей дополнил ответ. Нужно определиться по какому принципу выбрано это значение. Если нужно выбирать каждый раз минимальное значение, то это нужно указать явно в запросе.

Comment: А тогда ещё такой вопрос. Вот в первой выборке у меня во всех вариантах вторая дата меньше первой, ну как в принципе и указано в having, но когда я делаю второй вариант запросто просто с одной датой, бывает что вообще не выдаёт результатов. Я так понимаю дело в group by. Как сделать так что бы во втором варианте запроса у меня как раз таки были такие результаты в которых первая дата больше второй. Спасибо заранее. Если покажете на примере моего второго запроса буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Сейчас в вопрос добавлю пример выборки с которой не получается работать как нужно, запросы те же, только PIPE NUMBER меняется.

Comment: @Андрей Хорошая идея, ибо непонятно что имеется ввиду. Добавьте в вопрос результат, который Вы ожидаете получить.

Comment: То есть в итоге мне нужна 1 дата, так как добавится ещё 1 условие которое отрежет лишние варианты, но мне для начала нужно что на последней выборке которую я показал сработал второй запрос, но пока что увы он выдаёт пустой квери результ. Что не так подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Андрей добавил в ответ пояснения по разному результату между первой и второй выборкой. Общий комментарий: нужно четко сформулировать результат *словами*, а затем перейти к составлению запроса.