# sql. distinct, уникальные поля

Tags: sql

Всем привет!

Есть такая таблица в бд:

[image: http://joxi.ru/VrwYZbDiKgLeD2]

И такой запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Singer
FROM Artists
```

, таблица называется Artists.

Как можно усовершенствовать запрос так, чтобы он выдавал уникальное поле singer с другим полем, например с Sale.
Сейчас, результат запроса такой:

[image: http://joxi.ru/Vm6aV9EhxKJpMr]

Мне нужен такой результат:

[image: http://joxi.ru/p27RVbjH0Zq1nm]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: расположи всё в вопрос, а не ссылками на что-то еще. и надо бы не картинками, а нормальным отформатированным текстом

Comment: Мой вопрос в любом случае отредактируют, и скоро вместо ссылок будут картинки, тогда все будет понятно

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Singer, Sale FROM Artists` ?

Comment: Нет, так не работает должным образом, проверял уже, самый простой вариант

Comment: @Shillkas мы можем, но не должны за тебя форматировать. Я подумываю о том, что вопрос проще закрыть при таком отношении автора.

Comment: @Shillkas нужно наверное **сразу** уважать остальных участников, правда?

Comment: Использовать `GROUP BY` в запросе, вместо `DISTINCT`

Comment: Какую СУБД используете?

Comment: phpmyadmin конечно

Comment: @Shillkas phpmyadmin -  веб-интерфейс для администрирования СУБД, а не само СУБД

Comment: ок, mySql тогда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вопрос вроде немного непонятен, нo ответом является использование оконные функции (window functions) или самый простой способ это Group By

Comment: group by работает как и distinct, но позволяет вывести также и другие поля?

Comment: "проблемой" group by является то что тe столбца который вы хотите показать с помощью Select,должны перечислять в Group By.этот оператор группирует значение строк на основе перечисляемых данных

Comment: @Shillkas Нет, group by работает по другому, просто при _неправильном_ использовании в некоторых СУБД (старые MySQL, SQLite) он дает тот результат, который _похож_ на тот, что был нужен. Собственно вам надо задаться вопросом "какой именно sale мне нужен, если их будет несколько для одного Signer" и воспользоваться подходящей групповой функцией для поля Sale. подробнее про работу group by https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: Т.е. при таком запросе: `SELECT Singer, Sale AS FirstSale
FROM Artists
GROUP BY Singer` в Sale попадает массив всех значений, а не только 1-ое? И посредством функций sql можно найти максимальное, минимальное и т.д. А как найти первое значение?

Comment: @Shillkas не понятно чего Вы хотите-то? Вам же сказали ответить на вопрос "какой именно sale мне нужен, если их будет несколько для одного Signer" - так какой? Что значит "а не только 1-ое"? Вам нужно только первое значение? Определяться "первым" оно должно по какому критерию? Может просто использовать операторы `distinct, order by ` и `limit` ?

Comment: Нужно только 1-ое значение, да. 1-ое с каким столкнется sql исполнитель, ведь таблицу он проходит сверху вниз

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Singer, Sale FROM Artists LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Но ведь в вашем примере DISTINCT применяется и к Singer и к Sale, разве это будет работать как надо? Сойдет ли такой способ `SELECT Singer, FIRST(Sale) AS FirstSale FROM Artists GROUP BY Singer` ? с функцией FIRST()

Comment: Подскажите, а если в условии присутствует where, group by должно быть после where?

Comment: дa,GROUP BY должен быть после WHERE.у group by-a ест свой WHERE,который называется HAVING.