# mysql запрос к бд, из 3х таблиц на определённую(максимальную) дату и по типу цены, учитывая товары без цены

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести список товаров с последней ценой на определенную дату по определенному типу цены.
(Реализовать одним запросом).

Структура БД:

Product – товары (наименование, описание, статус)

- id
- title
- description
- status

DocPrice – документы. 
Содержит шапку документов. (номер документа, дата создания, тип цены, статус). Статус документа 0 – цены не отображаются, 1 – цена отображается

- Id
- datetime
- price_type(тип цены)
- status

DocPriceBody – таблица документов содержит список товаров и цену (товар, цена).

- Id
- doc_id
- product_id
- price

Примечание.
Создайте несколько документов с одним и тем же товаром и в запросе указывайте дату между документами. Так же учтите товар, который не имеет цены. т.е. не указан в документе, в списке тоже должен отображаться.

- Разобрал на подусловия.
  Есть 2-а подзапроса, выполняют необходимые действия.

Если возможно, как их лучше совместить в один не теряя их свойств?
    - Пробую соединять их также через LEFT JOIN.

- 1-ый подзапрос:
  Выбирает все товары из product которых нет в других таблицах( docprice, docpricebody )- т.е. не имеют цены,
  используется оператор LEFT JOIN + условие WHERE (  WHERE docpricebody.product_id IS NULL )

  ```
       SELECT product.id, product.title, product.description,
       docprice.datetime, docprice.price_type, docprice.status,
       docpricebody.doc_id, docpricebody.product_id, docpricebody.price 
       FROM 
         product 
               LEFT JOIN docpricebody ON( product.id = docpricebody.product_id ) 
               LEFT JOIN docprice     ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id )
       WHERE 
           docpricebody.product_id IS NULL
  ```
- 2-ой подзапрос:
  Выбирает все необходимые поля со связующей таблицы:
  по "типу цены"

  - по определённой заданной( максимальной ) "дате"
  - с последней "ценой" на эту дату

    ```
     SELECT docpricebody.product_id, product.*, docprice.* 
     FROM docpricebody, product, docprice 
     WHERE docpricebody.doc_id IN( 
                                    SELECT dp1.id 
                                    FROM docprice dp1 
                                            INNER JOIN ( 
                                                SELECT MAX(docprice.datetime) AS max_date, docprice.price_type, docpricebody.product_id 
                                                FROM docprice 
                                                        INNER JOIN docpricebody ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id ) 
                                                GROUP BY docpricebody.product_id 
                                                HAVING max_date <= date('2017-09-20') AND ( docprice.price_type = 'закупочная')
                                            ) dp2 ON ( dp1.datetime = dp2.max_date )  
                                ) 
             AND docpricebody.product_id = product.id  
             AND docpricebody.doc_id = docprice.id
    ```
- Есть общий, тестирую, но результат не точный.

  SELECT  product.id, product.title, product.description,
            docprice.datetime, docprice.price_type, docprice.status, 
            docpricebody.doc_id, docpricebody.product_id, docpricebody.price 
            FROM 
              product 
                  LEFT JOIN (

  ```
                       SELECT docpricebody.product_id
                       FROM docpricebody, product, docprice 
                       WHERE docpricebody.doc_id IN( 
                                          SELECT dp1.id 
                                          FROM docprice dp1 
                                                  INNER JOIN ( 
                                                      SELECT MAX(docprice.datetime) AS max_date, docprice.price_type, docpricebody.product_id 
                                                      FROM docprice 
                                                              INNER JOIN docpricebody ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id ) 
                                                      GROUP BY docpricebody.product_id 
                                                      HAVING max_date <= date('2017-09-20') AND ( docprice.price_type = 'закупочная')
                                                  ) dp2 ON ( dp1.datetime = dp2.max_date )  
                                      ) 
                      AND docpricebody.product_id = product.id  
                      AND docpricebody.doc_id = docprice.id 

              ) dpb ON ( dpb.product_id = product.id ) 
              LEFT JOIN docpricebody ON( product.id = docpricebody.product_id ) 
              LEFT JOIN docprice     ON( docprice.id = docpricebody.doc_id  ) 

        WHERE 
           docpricebody.product_id IS NULL 
           OR dpb.product_id IS NOT NULL
  ```

Дамп БД прилагается:

---

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `price_list` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `price_list`;
```

--

### -- Структура таблиці `docprice`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docprice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Дамп даних таблиці `docprice`

```
INSERT INTO `docprice` (`id`, `datetime`, `price_type`, `status`) VALUES
(1, '2017-09-04 00:00:00', 'закупочная', 0),
(2, '2017-09-04 00:00:00', 'закупочная', 1),
(3, '2017-09-05 00:00:00', 'мелкооптовая', 0),
(4, '2017-09-05 00:00:00', 'мелкооптовая', 1),
(5, '2017-09-06 00:00:00', 'оптовая', 0),
(6, '2017-09-06 00:00:00', 'оптовая', 1),
(7, '2017-09-07 00:00:00', 'плановая себестоимость', 0),
(8, '2017-09-07 00:00:00', 'плановая себестоимость', 1),
(9, '2017-09-08 00:00:00', 'розничная', 0),
(10, '2017-09-08 00:00:00', 'розничная', 1),
(12, '2017-09-15 00:00:00', 'закупочная', 0),
(13, '2017-09-17 00:00:00', 'закупочная', 0);
```

---

--

### -- Структура таблиці `docpricebody`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docpricebody` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Дамп даних таблиці `docpricebody`

```
INSERT INTO `docpricebody` (`id`, `doc_id`, `product_id`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 2500),
(2, 2, 2, 12500),
(3, 3, 5, 5000),
(4, 4, 6, 3000),
(13, 5, 9, 2499),
(14, 6, 10, 13000),
(15, 12, 1, 2600),
(16, 13, 1, 2700);
```

---

--

### -- Структура таблиці `product`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Дамп даних таблиці `product`

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Lenovo', 'телефон', 'в наличии'),
(2, 'Asus', 'ноутбук', 'в наличии'),
(3, 'Lenovo1', 'телефон', 'нет в наличии'),
(4, 'Asus1', 'ноутбук', 'нет в наличии'),
(5, 'goPro', 'видеокамера', 'в наличии'),
(6, 'Olympus', 'диктофон', 'в наличии'),
(7, 'goPro1', 'видеокамера', 'нет в наличии'),
(8, 'Olympus1', 'диктофон', 'нет в наличии'),
(9, 'nomi', 'смартфон', 'в наличии'),
(10, 'hp', 'ноутбук', 'в наличии'),
(11, 'nomi1', 'смартфон', 'нет в наличии'),
(12, 'hp1', 'ноутбук', 'нет в наличии'),
(13, 'PHILIPS', 'монитор', 'в наличии'),
(14, 'PHILIPS1', 'монитор', 'нет наличии');
```

--

### -- Індекси збережених таблиць

--

### -- Індекси таблиці `docprice`

```
ALTER TABLE `docprice`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

--

### -- Індекси таблиці `docpricebody`

```
ALTER TABLE `docpricebody`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

--

### -- Індекси таблиці `product`

```
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

--

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT для збережених таблиць

--

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблиці `docprice`

```
ALTER TABLE `docprice`
```

### MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=14;

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблиці `docpricebody`

```
ALTER TABLE `docpricebody`
```

### MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблиці `product`

```
ALTER TABLE `product`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=15;
```

Comment: Во втором запросе в having не может быть условия `docprice.price_type='закупочная'` потому что поля price_type нет в выражении group by Если в выборке будут записи с разными price_type для одного product_id то в having будет использовано первое попавшееся значение и какое именно предсказать невозможно. большинство sql вообще ошибку бы выдали на этом. А условие `max_date < ` в having так же очень странно выглядит для данных условий задачи, в выборку в принципе не попадут записи у которых есть более поздние цены. что то мне подсказывает, что большинство условий должно быть в where

Comment: А вообще лучше приведите структуру таблиц в виде готовых `create table` и еще к ним insert тестовых данных (можно на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com) потому что очень тяжело разбирать такие запросы чисто в уме, а тратить полчаса на создание таблиц и придумывание контрольного примера то же как то влом

Comment: Добавил содержимое дампа в вопрос, с условием 'docprice.price_type='закупочная' срабатывает без ошибок -  пробовал добавлять поле price_type в group by - к сожалению результат тот же. Условие 'max_date < ='  указано постановщиком, изначально вообще думал использовать для условия даты конструкцию LIKE.

Comment: Он срабатывает на ваших данных, но в общем виде он некорректен и потенциально приведет к скрытым ошибкам. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, благодарю за подсказку и уточнение. Оперативный ответ. Надо тестировать.

Comment: А зачем что то усиливать ? LEFT JOIN по умолчанию вам дает и те строки в которых цены нет и те в которых она есть. Если нужны только какие то конкретные из этих строк, то тогда вам нужно указанное условие что бы оставить только те что без цены или убрать слово LEFT если нужны только те у которых цена есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось что то в этом роде:

```
SELECT *
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT maxd.product_id, db.price
      FROM
        (SELECT db.product_id, max(d.datetime) max_date
           FROM docprice d
          INNER JOIN docpricebody db ON d.id = db.doc_id
          WHERE d.datetime <= date('2017-09-20') AND d.price_type = 'закупочная'
          GROUP BY db.product_id
        ) maxd
      JOIN docpricebody db ON db.product_id = maxd.product_id
      JOIN docprice d
        ON d.id = db.doc_id AND d.datetime=maxd.max_date AND d.price_type = 'закупочная'
  ) price ON price.product_id=p.id

WHERE price.product_id IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM docpricebody 
db WHERE db.product_id = p.id)
```

Но есть нюанс, запрос может дать некорректный результат (размножение записей) в случае если на одну и ту же дату-время (с точностью до секунд) будет более одного документа 'закупочная', содержащего один и тот же товар. В этом случае надо будет принять решение какой из документов или какую из цен по данному условию принимать в расчет.

Comment: Собственно с условием по последней цене на определённую дату всё отлично получилось. Вопрос в том как ещё усилить условие `LEFT JOIN` (было у меня ранее - `WHERE docpricebody.product_id IS NULL` ). Выбрать только товары, что не имеют цены. А именно, исходя из данных, так понимаю должно получиться 8 товаров что не имеют цены + 2 ( которые уже правильно выбираются ) с последней ценой и определёнными типом 'закупочная'.

Comment: @МаксимСлободянюк Сейчас запрос возвращает как товары с ценой, так и без подходящей цены. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3801f4f/1 Вам нужны не все, а только часть из них ?

Comment: Так понял из тз, что нужны только (без цены) + (только по типу, в данном случае 'закупочная'  и последней ценой), а остальные типы цены чтоб вообще не попадали. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: Грубо говоря, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3801f4f/1 - строки запроса с id = [5,6,9,10] чтобы не выбирались.

Comment: @МаксимСлободянюк Я эту строку в ТЗ понимаю как "товар не имеющий подходящей по вышеуказанным условиям цены". Просто я не могу представить в реальной жизни ситуации, при которой были бы интересны конкретные цены по отдельно заданным условиям типа даты и вида цены и при этом помимо них интересны товары у которых никаких видов цен ни на какие даты не задавалось. Но если это вдруг все так, как вы думаете, то тогда что то вроде `where price.product_id is not null
     OR not exists(select 1 from docpricebody db where db.product_id = p.id)`

Comment: Точный результат в соответствии с моим пониманием тз.