# Вывести список городов, в которых количество пользователей больше трех

Tags: mysql, sql

Не понимаю, почему ошибка?

> Invalid use of group function

Я знаю, что ругается на `WHERE COUNT(users.cities_id) > 3` но не знаю, почему?

```
SELECT cities.name, COUNT(users.cities_id) FROM cities 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.cities_id = cities.id 
WHERE COUNT(users.cities_id) > 3 GROUP BY cities.name
```

Comment: (не вчитываясь особо) WHERE на HAVING меняли?

Comment: поменял, получилась другая ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY cities.name
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

Comment: добавил HAVING COUNT(users.cities_id) > 3  после группировки и заработало, а почему так?

Comment: Поскольку вы не показываете, как переписали вопрос -- то я обязан спросить "а вы помните, что HAVING должен идти после GROUP BY" или тупо заменили одно слово на другое?

Comment: Почему заработало? М-м-м, ну объяснять подольше будет (тем более это сильно зависит от вашего текущего уровня понимания реляционных баз), а мне пора убегать. Если к вечеру никто не напишет ответ -- постараюсь не забыть про этот вопрос и напишу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условия с результатами групповых функций можно указывать только в части HAVING:

```
SELECT cities.name, COUNT(users.cities_id)
  FROM cities 
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.cities_id = cities.id 
 GROUP BY cities.name
HAVING COUNT(users.cities_id) > 3
```

Для понимания логики работы SQL запроса принято представлять порядок выполнения его частей следующим (в реальности СУБД для целей оптимизации делают чуть по другому):

1. from
2. ON в join
3. where
4. group by
5. having
6. select
7. order by
8. offset, limit

Все агрегатные функции вычисляются во время 4 фазы, когда [group by](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569) из первичных строк собирает суммарные. Во время выполнения фазы where, которая предназначена для работы с первичными строками таблиц, групп и результатов вычисления групповых функций еще нет, поэтому в этой фразе нельзя использовать агрегатные функции. Для фильтрации итоговых строк, образующихся во время группировки предназначена фраза having.

P.S. В принципе, если бы having не было (и в некоторых других случаях) тот же эффект можно получить так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT cities.name, COUNT(users.cities_id) as CNT
      FROM cities
      LEFT JOIN users ON users.cities_id = cities.id 
     GROUP BY cities.name
   ) X
 WHERE CNT > 3
```