# Долгая выборка простого запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT MIN(`cost`) FROM `shop_item` WHERE currency='rub';
```

Время выполнения 0,672 сек.

```
SELECT MIN(`cost`) FROM `shop_item` GROUP BY currency;
```

Выполнения 2,375 сек.

В таблице shop_item примерно 63000 записей.
Поле cost:INT; currency:ENUM и содержит всего 3 значения.
Индексы: cost:KEY; currency:KEY.
Обеспечение: SSD, Xeon x3450, XAMP, Windows 10.

Возможно ли ускорить данные запросы?

Comment: Первый запрос ускоряется созданием индекса (currency,cost). Второй просто не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Akina не могли бы вы пояснить почему второй вопрос не имеет смысла?

Comment: Он имел бы смысл, если бы выводилось не только MIN(cost), но и currency. А в нынешней форме получаешь ты пачку значений - и к чему их прикладывать?

Comment: Всё верно, в оригинале запрос больше и currency тоже запрашивается для GROUP. Укоротил запрос для упрощения понимания.

Comment: @Akina, извиняюсь за нубский вопрос, но не подскажете - где можно почитать про порядок исполнения директив запроса в mysql? (ну то есть - в каком порядке реально выполняются "select", "where", "order by" и т.д.) Просто без этого иногда совсем непонятно - какой нужно создать индекс, чтобы оптимизировать запрос.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762344/194569

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Akina.

после добавления составного индекса(currency,cost)

SELECT MIN(`cost`) FROM `shop_item` WHERE currency='rub';
Время выполнения 0,016 сек.

SELECT MIN(`cost`) FROM `shop_item` GROUP BY currency;
Выполнен за 0,031 сек.