# Выбор последних данных из БД кроме сегодняшних

Tags: mysql, select

Нужно получить последние данные для каждого **Name** без учета сегодняшних.
Например (сегодня, скажем, 07 янв 2018):

`id    Name    myDate   Val1   Val2
1     A    2018-01-07   10     15
2     A    2018-01-06    8     23
3     A    2018-01-05    6     11
4     B    2018-01-05   26     73
5     A    2018-01-03    1     44
6     B    2018-01-03   56     18
7     C    2018-01-02   66     88
...`

Мне нужен результат:

`2     A    2018-01-06    8     23
4     B    2018-01-05   26     73
7     C    2018-01-02   66     88`

Запрос, включая сегодняшние данные, выглядит так:

`select Name,myDate,Val1,Val2
    from myTable
    join (
        select Name, max(myDate) as myDate
            from myTable
            group by Name
    ) lastvalues using(Name, myDate)`

как исключить сегодняшние данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделав так - `where myDate < CURDATE()  group by Name` - вы найдете максимальные даты, не включая сегодня. и ваш запрос должен работать верно. Запрос полностью

```
select Name,myDate,Val1,Val2
    from myTable
    join (
        select Name, max(myDate) as myDate
            from myTable
            where myDate < CURDATE()
            group by Name
    ) lastvalues using(Name, myDate)
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a846/1)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть группировка, то достаточно будет WHERE `myDate` < :current_date. Где current_date = '2018-01-07'

Пример:

```
SELECT `Name`,`myDate`,`Val1`,`Val2`
FROM `myTable`
WHERE `myDate` < :current_date
GROUP BY `Name`
ORDER BY `myDate` DESC
```

Стоит учитывать, что при группировке MYSQL выполнить перебор всех подходящих записей. Т.е. все записи для A, B и т.п. И только потом сгруппирует - занесет в результат первый найденный.

Comment: Так вы получите val1 и val2 из неопределенных записей

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599772/194569

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @splash58 можете уточнить, почему неопределенных?

Comment: Почитайте ответ Mike по ссылке, которую он привел. кратко - при групповых операциях mysql ничего не гарантирует по поводу остальных полей - из которой записи он возьмет значения, как бы из первой встреченной. но какую он встретит первой... :)

Comment: для этого в моем примере в запросе ORDER BY, поэтому mysql первой встретит запись с максимальной датой и именно ее возьмет в результат