# Вывод количества проголосовавших

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Работаю над системой голосования на сайте, есть 3 таблицы: `quiz_quest` - вопросы, `quiz_answ` - варианты ответов, `quiz_uansw` - ответы посетителей. Вот такой код организовал:

```
$id = $_GET['quiz'];

    $answers = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM quiz_answ WHERE id_quiz_quest = $id");
    while ($r_a = mysqli_fetch_array($answers)) {

        $q_e_d_a = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count_answers FROM quiz_uansw WHERE id_quiz_question=$r_a[id_quiz_quest]");
        $rq = mysqli_fetch_array($q_e_d_a);

        if ($rq['id_quiz_answer'] && $rq['id_quiz_answer'] == $r_a['id']) {
            $count_answers = $rq['count_answers'];
            $smarty->assign('count_answers', $count_answers);
        } else {
            $smarty->assign('count_answers', '0');
        }

    }
```

то есть сначала первый запрос - это выбор всех из таблицы вариантов ответа всех ответов, принадлежащих к выбранному в GET-запросе вопросу, а затем запрос `$q_e_d_a` - выбираю количество проголосовавших именно за этот ответ, и задаю условие для показа количества: если этот ответ хотя бы раз выбрали и если он равняется тому, который сейчас используется в перебирающемся массиве `$r_a`, то мы показываем количество проголосовавших. Иначе выведем 0. Проблема в том, что он выводит 0 в любых случаях. Я подразумеваю, что это нужно делать другим циклом, но логически не могу сообразить, каким. Дайте подсказку плиз, а я доработаю сам)

Comment: может, в первом условии if нужно вместо "$rq['id_quiz_answer']" "$rq['count_answer']"?

Comment: и mysql у вас не ругается на синтаксис? вообще, возвращаемые из базы значения проверяли?

Comment: Просто выводится результат столько же раз, сколько записей выводится циклом. У меня один проголосовавший, так он выводит строку с единицей из бд в виде массива 9 раз

Comment: на какой из вопросов вы ответили? я не понимаю ваш ответ

Comment: На 2 вопрос, по первому вопросу исправил код, но также безуспешно

Comment: если запрос возвращает всё правильно, то проблема лишь в if. посмотрите, что дает false каждую итерацию, дело тупо в отладке, подход вроде бы правильный. если бы вы прикрепили к вопросу схему базы данных(хотя бы какие поля в таблицах), мне было бы легче понять логику запросов и условий проверки

Comment: Вы же надеюсь понимаете, что ваш второй запрос возвращает всегда только одну строку, в которой только столбец count_answers содержит корректные данные, а именно суммарное количество ответов на данный вопрос, причем любых ответов, а не какого то конкретного ответа. Во всех остальных полях это запрос возвращает все что угодно. т.е. `$rq['id_quiz_answer']` содержит id одного, случайного, ответа, а не какого то конкретного.

Comment: И еще, обратите внимание, что при переезде на другой хостинг и смене версии MySQL этот запрос  может начать давать ошибку, так как один запрос не имеет права возвращать одновременно и результат выполнения агрегатной функции (count()) и не группированные данные колонок (*), не включенных в предложение group by (а наличие count() автоматически делает group by до одной записи). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: А так же посмотрите внимательно на условия этого второго запроса и сравните с первым. в первом вы получаете только записи с одним конкретным id_quiz_quest, т.е. во всех записях он одинаков и при этом во втором запросе вы выбираете количество всех записей по этому же полю, т.е. ваш второй запрос гарантированно дает одно и то же на всех итерациях цикла. P.S. вообще выполнять какой либо запрос в цикле чтения из другого запроса это плохая идея и практика. Любые данные из SQL можно получить одним запросом

Comment: я пробовал конечно с INNER JOIN, но там лажа - выводились только значения, у которых имеются ответы, что и понятно собственно, поэтому в цикл все вставил

Comment: Все, разобрался) Всем спасибо за советы)

Comment: Вместо INNER нужен видимо LEFT JOIN