# GROUP BY в PDO как правильно написать запрос

Tags: php, pdo

Нужно сгрупировать все даты в БД при выводе при помощи `GROUP BY` написал функцию, которая выдает ошибку `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object` не могу понять в чем она заключается

```
 // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT id_shop, day FROM product_order GROUP BY day");
        $i = 0;
        $dayList = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $dayList[$i]['id_shop'] = $row['id_shop'];
            $dayList[$i]['day'] = $row['day'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $dayList;
```

Comment: после того как вызываете query напро проверить на ошибки, и если они есть вывести сообщения об этих ошибках. или включить вывод ошибок на уровне подключения. В любом случае скорее всего БД возвращает вам некую ошибку, просто вы ее игнорируете и поэтому не видете и не знаете что происходит

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017682/pdo-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-a-non-object
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349612/pdo-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-a-non-object

Comment: И очень вероятно, что ошибка БД связана с тем, что группируя по day вы пытаетесь вывести значение поля id_shop, но БД не знает id_shop какой именно записи из множества для группы надо вернуть (вы можете это задать применив например функции min/max к id_shop) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: зы: заметьте также, что имеется метод `fetchAll` и в написании цикла нет никакой необходимости.

Comment: @teran можно по подробней

Comment: что тут подробней, вы в цикле делаете `fetch` по одной записи. Можно сделать [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) и не писать этот цикл.

Comment: @teran т.е так `return $result->fetchAll();`?

Comment: вроде того. там параметры еще у метода есть. но ошибка ваша все равно на уровне выполнения запроса и `result = false` скорее всего.