# group by в запросе мешает выполнению запроса

Tags: mysqli

Господа, доброго дня всем

```
SELECT
    `p`.`id`,
    `p`.`price`*`settings`.`value` as `price_sell`
FROM                                                               
    `table1` as `p`
INNER JOIN 
    `table2` as `pt` ON `p`.`id`=`pt`.`id_product`     
INNER JOIN 
    `table3` as `settings`                  
WHERE 1 AND `settings`.`key`='delimiter'
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
ORDER BY `p`.`param1` DESC, `p`.`param2` ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

В общем есть такой запрос. Локально на MySQL 5.7 выполняется на ура. На хостинге - проблема

```
Ошибка в запросe (1055):
Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mybd.settings.value'
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Тут 2 пути, переделать запрос, или понять почему на хостинге запрос не идет, а локально работает. Прошу подскажите решение, что лучше предпринять. есть ли настройка MySQL которая может отличаться, или придется запрос переписывать? и если дело касается запроса, то как переписать?

Comment: В списке выборки не должно быть голых колонок, не перечисленных в group by, необходимо явно задавать какое значение из нескольких возможных должно быть показано, т.е. указывать функции min/max/avg и т.п. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569  В вашем случае все колонки таблицы p, используемые в списке выборки и order by можно указать в group by, так как они все равно уникальны. по колонкам других таблиц надо принимать решение по каждой какое же значение вы хотите брать

Comment: GROUP BY `p`.`id`, `settings`.`id` - второй параметр, помогло, спс! Прошу, пост в ответы, надо за акцептить, может кому пригодиться решение

Comment: А вы уверены, что settings.id можно добавлять в group by ? т.е. вы уверены, что на один p.id приходится гарантированно не более одного settings.id ? Если так, то не совсем понятно, зачем вообще нужен group by

Comment: Уберите `GROUP BY` - оно совершенно бессмысленно, поскольку нет групповых функций, но добавьте `DISTINCT`. Если оно вообще надо - уж больно `p.id` на первичный индекс походит...

Comment: GROUP BY надо. я там в запросе указал table2! из за него там дубли в ID. в settings у меня есть и другие параметры, left JOIN выбирает определенный, по моему ключику = delimiter. я только не понял почему локально ошибки не было, а на хосте появилась