# Аггрегирование в объединенной таблице

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. `Payment` и `Player`. Я объединил их через `LEFT JOIN`. 
Я объединил их через запрос

```
SELECT payment.id, 
       payment."createTime" as "Дата платежа",  
       payment."playerId" as "ИД игрока",  
       payment."currencyAmount" as "Потрачено",  
       player."createTime" as "Дата регистрации" 
FROM payment
LEFT JOIN player ON payment."playerId"=player.id
```

Я хочу сгруппировать таблицу по "Дате регистрации" и просуммировать колонку "Потрачено". Как только добавляю функцию `SUM` - система говорит что я должен еще сгруппировать по всем колонкам, а я хочу только по одной колонке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Система вам абсолютно правильно говорит, потому что она не знает что делать если для одной группы окажется несколько разных значений в колонке, какое из значений вам надо в итоге выдать. Это вы должны указать сами, применив соответствующие групповые функции https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599772/194569

Comment: @Mike а как обойти это_?) сгруппировать по одной только колонке

Comment: Все колонки не участвующие в group by должны быть заключены в групповые функции. min/max/sum/avg выбирайте какое из значений для группы вы хотите в них видеть и пишите соответствующие функции. Если у вас за одну дату два платежа а на выходе вы хотите получить только одну строку, то id какого из платежей вы хотите в ней увидеть ?

Comment: "Объединил через JOIN" - это оксюморон какой-то. JOIN - соединение, а объединение - UNION.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT payment.id, 
       payment.createTime,  
       payment.playerId,  
       SUM(payment.currencyAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY player.createTime),  
       player.createTime 
  FROM payment
  LEFT JOIN player 
    ON payment.playerId = player.id
```