# LEFT JOIN Дублирует поля [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Столкнулся с проблемой дублирования полей при использовании LEFT JOIN в MySQL запросе.

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, topics.topic_date, topics.topic_views 
FROM topics 
LEFT JOIN categories
ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN posts
ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic
WHERE categories.cat_id = 1
ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC;
```

---

По идее, данный запрос должен выводить топики с сортировкой по последнему по времени посту в них. Он их выводит, но дублирует в зависимости от количества постов внутри топиков. Искал готовое решение, смотрел GROUP BY, но не понял как применить это в данном случае :<

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: может быть distinct ?

Comment: В group by указывайте все поля, которые выбираете в select, а в order by берите `max(posts.post_date)` вам же надо отсортировать по дате самого последнего поста ? И таблица categories в запросе вообще не нужна, в where спокойно можно проверять `topics.topic_cat=1`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ distinct собьет сортировку

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как его сюда впихнуть? Пробовал, ошибка в синтаксе.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за первый LEFT JOIN и за остальное тоже. Все заработало, правда не совсем понял почему без max(posts.post_date) выдает ошибку..

Comment: @RoofLee Потому что после group by выходит, что для одной строки (топика) есть несколько дат постов и mysql не знает какой же из них применить. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: @Mike Кстати, я натыкался на этот пост, но от первой строки у меня сильно заболела голова и я убежал оттуда :D Спасибо еще раз, не могу репутейшен накинуть, так как нужно минимум 15 самому:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Спасибо @Mike

> В group by указывайте все поля, которые выбираете в select, а в order by берите max(posts.post_date) вам же надо отсортировать по дате самого последнего поста ? И таблица categories в запросе вообще не нужна, в where спокойно можно проверять topics.topic_cat=1