# Как вывести одно значение с каждой группы ( последняя запись каждой группы)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Задача:** Вывести одно последнию строку с каждой группы (`station`).
**Моя проба:** Используя `GROUP BY station`, я получил желаемый результат однако тут возник вопрос к сортировке. `Order by` в моем случае сортирует уже готовый список.

**Мой запрос:**

```
SELECT * FROM `logs` GROUP BY `station` ORDER BY `logs`.`TimeStamp` DESC
```

[image: Таблица logs]

Comment: конечно отсортировать можно только после группировки. вообще применение `*` и order by по дате в присутствии group by не корректен, какой результат вы хотите получить ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s0.* FROM
(SELECT s.id FROM logs s WHERE station=a.station ORDER BY id DESC) strid
FROM logs a GROUP BY station  ) t 
JOIN logs s0 ON s0.id=t.strid
ORDER BY id DESC
```

так будет быстрее, но обязательно убедиться, что есть нужные индексы. таблицы логов могут быть безумных размеров.

Comment: в ответе выше ") t" - это что?

Comment: every derived table must have its own alias - иначе будет ошибка

Comment: "every derived table must have its own alias - иначе будет ошибка – armadillo'"
Это я понял. Но эта скобка закрывающая ничего не закрывает. На весь код одна открывающая и две закрывающих