# Как выбрать уникальные значение с привязкой по дате MySql?

Tags: mysql

Не могу, выполнит выборку. Буду благодарен любой помощи.
Мне нужно вытащить все id c уникальным столбцом blog_id где дата <= CURRENT_DATE
выбираю по title_id.

[image: Вот моя таблица]

Т.е передаю в title_id = 1 и нужно получить blog_id только 1,2 по одному, но по ближайший  дате.

Выполняю запрос такой

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT * 
       FROM test 
       WHERE title_id = 1 
       ORDER BY date_article DESC) AS s  
GROUP_BY s.blog_id
```

но blog_id = 1 выбирается средняя дата

Comment: А как **вы** пытаетесь это сделать? Какой запрос?

Comment: SELECT * FROM  (SELECT * FROM test WHERE title_id = 1 ORDER BY date_article DESC) AS s  GROUP_BY s.`blog_id`

Comment: Добавьте: DDL таблицы, тестовые данные, эталонный ответ для тестовых данных. А фотографию можно удалить.

Comment: `select blog_id, max(date_article) from test where title = 1 group by blog_id`

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY используется только с определенными операторами как SUM, COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT возможно есть еще что-то. Без них у вас выйдет ошибка. Об этом более подробно рассказал 
 пользователь [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) вот в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql).

В вашем случае должно помочь

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(blog_id) FROM test) ORDER BY date_article DESC;
```