# Убрать повторяющиеся поля из результата запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT `n`.*, `i`.`img`, `c`.`chpu` AS `man_chpu`, `c`.`name` AS `man_name` FROM `product` AS `n`
 LEFT JOIN `product_category` AS `cp` ON cp.product = n.id
 LEFT JOIN `category` AS `c` ON cp.category = c.id WHERE (c.is_manufacturer=1) AND (c.parent=0) AND (n.article LIKE '%1062%') ORDER BY `n`.`name` ASC LIMIT 10'
```

Он проходится по таблице связывающей продукты с категориями `product_category` , в которой 3 столбца:

```
id, product (id продукта), category (id рубрики к которой он привязан)
```

и по полученным там id продуктов выбирает информацию о них из таблицы `product`.

Проблема в том, что 1 продукт может принадлежать нескольким категориям и в результирующей выборке будет несколько (столько - скольким категориям он принадлежит) одинаковых значений. Мне надо оставить только уникальные.

Comment: вроде должно быть. очевидно, что не получится оставить столбец с категорией и сделать уникальную выборку? Либо убираете столбец вообще, либо агрегируете

Comment: Внезапно решил с помощью `GROUP BY`

Comment: только скорее всего не правильно :) оно конечно работает, но необходимо применять агреггирующие функции ко всем полям, не участвующим в gruop by, что бы точно понимать, что именно будет получено. И заодно что бы запрос вдруг не перестал работать на другой версии/с другими настройками MySQL. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599772/194569