# Почему запрос выполняется неверно?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Есть вот такой пример: [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595fdf/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/595fdf/3) Я ожидаю что вернутся записи с id 2 и 3, а возвращаются 1 и 3. Что не так и как исправить?

```
create table chat_messages
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    room_id int not null,
    message varchar(255) not null,
    created_at timestamp null
);

insert into chat_messages (room_id, message, created_at) values
(1, 'message 1', NOW()),
(1, 'message 2', NOW() + interval 1 hour),
(2, 'message 3', NOW() + interval 2 hour);

select *
from chat_messages
where room_id in (1, 2)
group by room_id
order by created_at desc;
```

Comment: При группировке возвращаются случайные записи, а не конкретные. Поэтому это рандом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но я же сортировку сделал!

Comment: Эта не та сортировка. Это сортировка окончательной выборки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как сделать так как я хочу? Мне нужны именно последние сообщения от каждой комнаты.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает GROUP BY в MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-group-by-%d0%b2-mysql)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вообще не похоже. Там сортировки нет.

Comment: Там написано как работает группировка и о целесообразности выборки неаггрегированных полей

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да ладно, зря удалил. Вроде убедил меня уже. Я хотел принять ответ))

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```sql
Select * from chat_messages c
join (select max(created_at) as max_created, room_id
From chat_messages
Group by room_id
) m 
on c.group_id = m.group_id and
c.max_created = m.max_created
```

Как-то так
Group by оператор берет первое попавшееся значеие (то, что успел прочитать) поэтому приходится сначала группировать одну часть в подзапросе, а потом джоинить окончательный результат.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Лучше эту задачу разбить на две части. Сначала напишем запрос, который найдет максимальный `id` для каждого `room_id`:

```
SELECT 
   room_id, 
   MAX(id) AS MaxId
 FROM chat_messages
 GROUP BY room_id
```

После этого с помощью `INNER JOIN` этот запрос объединим с выборкой из таблицы `chat_messages`. Таким образом, будут выбраны строки целиком из таблицы `chat_messages`, но только те, которые были найдены в первом запросе:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM chat_messages AS cm
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
       room_id, 
       MAX(id) AS MaxId
     FROM chat_messages
     GROUP BY room_id) group_diff 
ON cm.room_id = group_diff.room_id 
AND cm.id = group_diff.MaxId;
```

Ссылка: [Получить id пользователя, сумму и дату первой выплаты](https://ittx.ru/note/2021/03/16/sql-query-example/#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_id_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)