# Синтаксис SQL, не могу разобраться с запросом

Tags: sql, select

**Получите список и общее число студентов указанных групп или указанного курса указанного факультета, сдавших указанную сессию на отлично, без троек, без двоек.**

Есть таблица СТУДЕНТ и таблица ОЦЕНКА
Нужно исключить из вывода Данные студента,если хотя бы в одной записи таблицы ОЦЕНКА в поле оценка у него стоит НЕУД

Работал над запросом, выводит строку, где у конкретного студента стоит оценка 5, даже если по другим предметам оценки хуже

Comment: Так покажите запрос который получился, готовый доработать быстрее. А так как минимум два пути: 1. использовать подзапрос "not exists" или сделать join, group by и в having написать условие, которое зависит от того что такое "неуд" и есть ли значения меньше него. (например если неуд это 2 и 1 то же неуд, то в having писать условие min(оценка) > 2)

Comment: Сохранился только такой запрос(остальные по мере понимания, что они не рабочие,откидывал), он по сути тоже не особо полезный. Есть студент у которого по Экономике стоит зачет, а по математике неЗачет, строку с неЗачетом он откидывает, но вот вторую все равно выводит, в запросе нет прохождения по всей таблице, а как это сделать я не знаю

Comment: SELECT  `student`.`Name`, `student`.`Surname`, `student`.`Patronymic`, `grade`.`Grade`  FROM `student` 
INNER JOIN `grade` ON `grade`.`id_Student` = `student`.`id_Student` HAVING  `grade` = "Зачет"

Comment: ну вот, добавить group by, потому что без него на выходе будет всего одна запись, полная "сумма" всех строк (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-group-by-%d0%b2-mysql/599802#599802) А в having можно использовать только агрегатные функции, а не сами поля, потому что после группировки уже никаких исходных строк и исходных полей (кроме участвующих в group by) нет, а есть только собранные итоговые.

Comment: Если там не числа и не понятно как отработают min/max, то использовать конструкции вроде `sum(case when grade != 'Зачет' then 1 end) = 0`

Comment: Спасибо, пошел разбираться

Comment: Еще как вариант не использовать группировки и having, inner join заменить на left join (он пропускает в том числе строки, для которых по условиям on ничего не нашлось в правой таблице) т.е. `left join grade on grade.id_Student = student.id_Student and grade != 'Зачет'` посмотреть результат, обратить внимание, что на выходе получили либо записи с НЕ зачетными оценками либо отдельные записи студентов с NULL во всех полях grade (так как их не нашлось с НЕ зачетом). понять что именно пустые то нам и нужны, добавить `where grade.id_Student IS NULL` (where работает уже после join)

Comment: получил вот такой результат, потестил, вроде работает исправно

Comment: SELECT `student`.`id_Student`, `student`.`Surname`, `student`.`Name`, `student`.`Patronymic`, SUM(CASE WHEN `grade`.`Grade` != "Зачет" AND `grade`.`Grade`!=5 AND `grade`.`Grade`!="Отл." then 1 else 0 end) FROM `student` 
INNER JOIN `grade` on `grade`.`id_Student` = `student`.`id_Student` 
GROUP BY `student`.`id_Student`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `grade`.`Grade` != "Зачет" AND `grade`.`Grade`!=5 AND `grade`.`Grade`!="Отл." then 1 else 0 end) = 0