# column X must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT version();
                                                           version                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
```

Есть таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE levels (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(61) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE contents (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    level_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES levels(id)
);
```

В них есть какие-то записи, я пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос:

```
WITH contents2 AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        (SELECT l.title FROM levels l WHERE l.id=c.level_id) AS level_name
    FROM contents c
)
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.level_name
FROM contents2 c
GROUP BY c.id
```

На что postgres говорит мне:

```
ERROR:  column "c.title" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Я понимаю что значит эта ошибка, таким образом postgres говорит что для той или иной колонки в SELECT есть несколько вариантов для выдачи. Но в данном случае, абсолютно очевидно, что должно быть в c.title, там просто нет других вариантов, но почему он выдаёт мне эту ошибку? Мне надо писать каждую колонку в `GROUP BY` чтобы он не выкидывал эту ошибку?

Comment: *В них есть какие-то записи, я пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос* Формулируйте саму задачу, а не только свою попытку её решить.

Answer (score 1):

т.к. СУБД не понимает, что делать с этим полем, необходимо явно указать/

Необходимо все перечисляемые поля добавить в GROUP BY(по этим полям группируем данные)

```
WITH contents2 AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        (SELECT l.title FROM levels l WHERE l.id=c.level_id) AS level_name
    FROM contents c
)
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.level_name
FROM contents2 c
GROUP BY c.id, c.title, c.level_name
```

Поля, которые не перечислены в GROUP BY можно использовать в запросе, но только вместе с агрегатными функциями

```
WITH contents2 AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        (SELECT l.title FROM levels l WHERE l.id=c.level_id) AS level_name
    FROM contents c
)
SELECT c.id, count(c.title), count(c.level_name), count(*)
FROM contents2 c
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: И давно это в постгрес? По-моему в более раних версиях это работало без перечисления всех нужных полей в group by. Я склоняюсь к тому что это баг, потому что никакого логического объяснения почему оно так должно работать нет

Comment: Если я правильно перевел, [документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) говорит об обратном. Есть исключения, но общие правила остаются

Comment: В postgres это вроде бы как всегда. Вот mysql позволяет больше свободы при таких запросах.

Comment: @Inventor *Я склоняюсь к тому что это баг, потому что никакого логического объяснения почему оно так должно работать нет* Наоборот. Если работает - вот это бага. Некоторые СУБД делают из него фичу - за счёт получения недетерминированного результата.

Comment: @Inventor Вот логическое объяснение почему так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: @Akina если у меня 20 полей в таблице то мне надо все 20 перечислять в GROUP BY? Это же очень удобно, есть какой-то способ не делать этого?

Comment: очень не удобно*

Comment: Если вы собираетесь группировать по всем 20 столбцам, да писать немного дольше придется, но вопрос, зачем вам такая группировка?

Comment: @Inventor Если у Вас в таблице 20 полей, и надо группировать по ВСЕМ - то поневоле возникает вопрос - а нахрена вообще группировать? может, хватит вульгарного DISTINCT? *если у меня 20 полей в таблице то мне надо все 20 перечислять в GROUP BY?* Текст запроса меньше всего определяется тем, удобен он кому-то или нет. Он определяется требуемой логикой. И если эта логика требует перечисления 20 полей - будь любезен перечислить и не ныть.

Comment: @SwaD я не хочу группировать по всем, но иначе постгрес будет жаловаться и выдавать вышеуказанную ошибку. Вот в том примере выше. Допустим в таблице contents 20 полей, а не 3 и мне надо все 20 получить. И пока я все 20 не укажу в group by он не даст мне результат

Comment: @Inventor Если вам надо просто вывести все строки, уберите `group by`. Если нужен сгруппированный результат, то перечисляются все поля для группировки. Если вы хотите увидеть просто уникальные наборы всех комбинаций ваших полей, уберите `group by` и после select добавьте `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
WITH contents2 AS (
    SELECT
        c.*,
        (SELECT l.title FROM levels l WHERE l.id=c.level_id) AS level_name
    FROM contents c
)
SELECT c.id, MAX(c.title) AS title, MAX(c.level_name) AS level_name
FROM contents2 c
GROUP BY c.id
```

Выглядит как костыль, но на самом деле довольно часто используется и не захламляет предложение `GROUP BY`

**UPD:** для искушённых.
Сложность алгоритма сортировки +- `O(N*Ln(N))` - поиск максимума `O(N)`, т.е. `MAX` в предложении `SELECT` не только увеличивает читабельность кода, но и освобождает оптимизатор сервера от ненужных действий. Да, в `MySQL` по умолчанию оно и так сработает, но на мой взгляд это бага, а не фича.